# Filter and then aggregate two datasets in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two datasets, df1 and df2, where I would like to perform a join, set a filter and then perform an aggregate.

df1

```
version host    date                                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019   
fam     a16     12/1/2019   
emp     a16     12/1/2019   
dan     a16     12/1/2019
```

df2

```
name    purpose  date
pat     hi       12/1/2019
fam     cat      12/1/2019
hello   dog      12/1/2019
dan     bird     12/1/2019
```

Here are the join results:

```
version host    date                 name    purpose       date                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019            pat     hi            12/1/2019
fam     a16     12/1/2019            fam     cat           12/1/2019
```

**DESIRED**

```
version    host    date             name      purpose   date
2          a16     12/1/2019        2         2         12/1/2019
```

**DOING**

```
    select    count(df1.version), df1.host, df1.date, count(df2.name),count(df2.purpose), df2.date
    from      df1
    left join df2
    on        df1.version = df2.name  AND
              df1.date    = df2.date
    where     df2.purpose = 'hi' OR df2.purpose = 'cat'
    group by  df1.host
```

However, I am not getting the desired result with a count for the desired columns. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your query should fail, because the `select` columns are not consistent with the `group by` columns.  What result are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another two group by clauses should fix.

Try `GROUP BY df1.host, df2.date, df1.date`

Comment: Ok I will try this. Thank you

Comment: @Lynn, I forgot to add another df1.date, now it should work, you can check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/132c46/2

Answer (score 0):

I created tables df1 and df2 in mysql and it gives the desired result, using your script. my tables may be slightly different in structure to yours and you mentioned SQL and there are differences in how SQL and mySql work. Are you using SQL or mySQL?

Comment: Using SQLServer

Comment: are your datasets tables? unusual to join like that. I would like to see your table structures if you can share?